# Which 3D object format is better with three.js

Tags: three.js

If someone is working on a webgl-three.js context using many 3D objects (with textures,slight movement and mouse listeners) which format is more suitable to use to import them; JSON  or OBJMTL ?

I can make both work,I just want to know which is best before starting writting much code and then realize I should have done it that way.

**NOTE: .obj and .mtl files seem to have much less information about the vertices etc than the .js files. is that a bad sign as far as the quality of rendering is concerned?**

Comment: with very little code you can support both.

Comment: what about the quality (see NOTE) ?

Answer (score 1):

JSON is preferable.

- It is more concise and loading is faster
- Browser can load it directly into JavaScript data structures
- JSON format accommodates more than one material for a single mesh
- Three.js has a binary equivalent to its text-based JSON format